# Sending an eMail, when a form is submitted

Tags: php, forms, email

I am using Dreamweaver to create a simple coming soon website. However when I click the submit button on my form, it just opens my default mail application and asks me to send the email. I then made a php that is meant to send the email. If anyone could look at it, I would be greatly appreciated. If you fix the php, could you give me the whole version, I am not very good at this stuff and don't understand most of it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Fiction Filming</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon3.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
}
</style>
<link href="Css/singlePageTemplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n2:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Main Container -->
<div class="container"> 
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <!-- Hero Section -->
  <!-- About Section -->
  <!-- Stats Gallery Section -->
  <div class="gallery"><img src="Images/Newbannercomingsoon.png" alt="" width="1000" height="500" class="logo-pic"/> </div>
  <!-- Parallax Section -->
  <!-- More Info Section -->
  <!-- Footer Section -->
  <section class="footer_banner" id="contact">

<form class="subscribeForm form-fix" name="Subscription Form" method="post" action="mailform.php">
            <div class="newform">
              <div> </div>
              <div>
                <input id="fname" type="text" placeholder="NAME" name="name" required>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input name="email" type="email" required id="email" placeholder="EMAIL">
              </div>
              <div>
                <select name="select" required id="myselect">
                  <option>HELP / SUPPORT</option>
                  <option>BUSINESS ENQUIRES</option>
                  <option>OTHER</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="text-form">
                <div>
                  <textarea name="textarea" required id="textarea" placeholder="TYPE YOUR TEXT HERE"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br><input name="Send" type="submit" id="Send" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
<!-- Step 1: Add an email field here -->

<!-- Step 2: Add an address field here -->
            <!-- Step 3: add a submit button here -->

</section>
  <!-- Copyrights Section -->
<div class="copyright">&copy;2016 - <strong>Fiction filming</strong></div>
</div>
<!-- Main Container Ends -->
</body>
</html>
```

**And Here is the PHP**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="3;URL=thankyou.html">
<title>Email Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

// Or the below if using "name="Send" for the input. Uncomment and get rid of the above
// if(isset($_POST['Send'])){
    $to = "nicholas@fictionfilming.com";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $sender_name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['select'];
    $textarea = $_POST['textarea'];
    $body = $sender_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $textarea;
    $subject = $subject;
    mail($to,$subject,$body);

    if(mail($to,$subject,$body)){
    echo "Mail was sent. Check both your inbox and spam, as mail as done its job.";
}
else{
    echo "There was a problem. Check your logs.";
}
    }

   // $headers = "From:" . $from;
   // $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    //echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    //}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nicholas, first of all certify yourself that both of files are at the same folder. 2) the files must be in a website, I mean hosted in a machine from an ISP, under a public IP and set with a sendmail service. 3) change the line `<br><input name="Send" type="submit" id="Send" value="Send">` to `<br><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">`

Comment: Ok. All of the files are in the same folder, on a website that has the mail command. I tried changing the line you said, I will tell you if it works

Comment: It is interesting, cause here it seems all is working.

Comment: That said, it seems the matter is with the process of delivering the mail. Are you sure the code you have is correct? Did you get it as a sample code from your ISP? Well... a new try: change this line `<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="3;URL=thankyou.html">` to this `<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="30;URL=thankyou.html">` cause only 3 seconds may not be all the time your process is needing to go. Then, if the processing isn't done and the time is over, 3 secs, "thankyou.html" is called and sendmail is cancelled. Try with 30, if it works, down that number to 5, for example, just to test.

Comment: Thank you, It all works fine... Finally, all solved! Oh, I just saw your last message. It does work!

Comment: How do I solve this if it is a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicholas, first of all certify yourself that both of files are at the same folder. 2) the files must be in a website, I mean hosted in a machine from an ISP, under a public IP and set with a sendmail service. 3) change the line

**`<br><input name="Send" type="submit" id="Send" value="Send">`**

to

**`<br><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">`**